# Upload photo from my system to company Facebook page without having users authenticate individually

Tags: facebook, coldfusion

I have an application where my staff upload photos for specific tours.  My priority is to have the photos uploaded to my system to use in my site and product display.  However, every time any of my staff upload a photo in my system, I want to send the photo to our corporate facebook presence.  Preferably with a little story about each photo.

Everything I have found seems to require each user to log in with their own facebook accounts individually.  Is there a way to code authentication with my facebook account details regardless of who the user is and then take the photo uploaded on my system using cffile and send it to our corporate facebook presence?

I would post code attempts here, but at this point I am still not sure if this is possible.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.....

Comment: I've recently been working on integration with facebook and twitter using coldfusion.  Facebook seems to require each user to grant permission to generate the login key at time of the initial session.  However, twitter on the other hand, allows you to generate a token for the user that you could store in your application to bypass the permission area.  So, I think what your asking for can't be done on facebook.

Comment: Hey Steve....thanks for this.  I have been digging and it looks like that is true but not at the page level.  Using the Graph API it looks like you can use an administrator login for FB on the CF side and have the CF update the page.

Comment: if that is true, it would be great if you could post a sample of the code to as an answer to your question below.  I'd like to see how you handle that.

Comment: Hey Steve...I will totally post my solution.  However, something came up and i will not get to this for a few weeks.  In the meantime, here is a link to the documentation for FB Page interactions.  Read the section on Page access tokens that covers this method. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Answer (score 3):

posting photo with some text is possible on Facebook using your system. all you need to do is to visit [developer.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/) and register an app and get the required authentication key. and follow  documentation of graph API. ColdFusion Facebook SDK is also available on [Git Hub](https://github.com/affinitiz/facebook-cf-sdk). that makes you job more easy.

Comment: Hi Keshav...thanks for answering.  My main concern was that the Graph seemed to force each user to log in individually.  However, I discovered that if you only want to post to a page, you can do this with one FB page administrator login and avoid having your users login to their FB accounts.  I have not got it up and running yet, but the documentation seems pretty clear on this.

Comment: after authentication facebook send some data like username,userid,acesstoken  that you can store in database and use it for authentication. you don't need to authenticate your facebook app again. if you want all your staff can post on facebook page. you can then autheicate facebook api at application level using above data or if you want only some staff can acess it then you need to set permission for those staff and at session level you it will be authenticated.